# Required attribute on custom classes

Tags: c#, validation, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building an MVC 5 app and have come to the point where I need to validate user input.

I would like to apply a [Required] attribute to a class that is not a built-in data type. Here is a snippet of my view model:

```
public class GraffitiViewModel : EformBase
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select yes or no")]
    public RadioButtonList<YesNoType> GraffitiOffensive { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select yes or no")]
    public RadioButtonList<YesNoType> GraffitiTag { get; set; }
    // ... more stuff here
}
```

The RadioButtonList is a class that emits HTML markup for corresponding C# radio button definitions. The [Required] attribute is not working in this context. Is there a way I can extend either my RadioButtonList class, or the [Required] attribute, so I don't have to modify my ViewModel?

I am thinking along the lines of a custom attribute that will perform this validation or a method in my RadioButtonList that will return a bool indicating whether or not the validation succeeded.

Looking forward to your responses!

M

Comment: why not use booleans?

Answer (score 1):

The `[Required]` attribute should fire if:

- the property is null
  OR
- the property is a string type, which is either empty or whitespace

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) for more details.

Alternatively you can use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879579/61697) to create a custom attribute which fires on whatever conditions you decide.