# How to add a method in a property C# (like something.ToString())

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I'm creating a custom class in c# and I want to add a method in a property

So, a custom method in a property for example it's *like the ToString method*. But I want to **create** a new one in a property with **attributes**

(like this:

```
using System;

namespace foo.Example
{
    public class foo
    { 
        object object = new object();
        string test = object.Something(); //Like ToString()
    }
}
```

but the ToString() method in any objects like classes, methods, *properties*, etc). I want to add a method into a property like what I said above with the object with the .ToString() method in a property and anything.

I actually tried this: [How to create a custom attribute in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879521/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-in-c-sharp) but it doesn't work, I tried everything but there are not many examples in Google and some are outdated.

I tried this (I want to add ToInt method, ToDouble (It's more efficient)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Winforms.Something.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class PropertyToValueAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public PropertyToValueAttribute() { }

        public int ToInt()
        {
            object value = 0;
            Type type = this.GetType();
            IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(type.GetProperties());
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                value = prop.GetValue(this, null);
            }

            return Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }

        public double ToDouble()
        {
            object value = 0;
            Type type = this.GetType();
            IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(type.GetProperties());
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                value = prop.GetValue(this, null);
            }

            return Convert.ToDouble(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I did that in the class where I want to use the property:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Winforms.Something.Attributes;

namespace Winforms.Something
{
    [Serializable]
    public class AttributedClass
    {
        private double _propexample;
        [PropertyToValue]
        public double Property
        {
            get { return _propexample; }
            set { _propexample = value; }
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you use the property?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand your question but I have a feeling that extension method might be what you need.

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static void YourTypeExtension(this YourType self) {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as following:

```
public class A {
    public void Method() {
        var yourType = new YourType();
        yourType.YourTypeExtension();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the closest the OP is going to get to what they want.  The catch is that extension methods do not have access to private members of the class.

Comment: That's can be the key to the solution but something a "Property" (I searched) doesn't have is a type (You cannot use it). Anyway thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use getter and setter for your property
So like this:

```
public class foo
{
  public object Test = new();
  public string TestString { get => Test.ToString(); }
}
```

your getter can be multiple lines:

```
public class foo
{
  public object Test = new();

  public string TestString
  {
    get
    {
        return Test.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Use this Link for more: [Properties](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-properties-in-C-Sharp/#:%7E:text=Property%20in%20C%23%20is%20a,accessor%20and%20set%20property%20accessor.)

Comment: Hello, you are very nice but I forgot to add something. I meant add a method in a property like the ToString method. I edited the first example code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an expression-bodied property TestString like this:

```
public class foo
{
    public object Test = new();

    public string TestString => Test.ToString();
}
```

This is the equivalent of the TestString property only having a getter and no setter