# Get property value to use within custom attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

I have been looking for an example of how to get a property's value from within a custom attribute's code.

Example for illustration purposes only:  We have a simple book class with only a name property.  The name property has a custom attribute:

```
public class Book
{
    [CustomAttribute1]
    property Name { get; set; }
}
```

Within the custom attribute's code, I would like to get the value of the property on which the attribute has been decorated:

```
public class CustomAttribute1: Attribute
{
    public CustomAttribute1()
    {
        //I would like to be able to get the book's name value here to print to the console:
        // Thoughts?
        Console.WriteLine(this.Value)
    }
}
```

Of course, "this.Value" does not work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916904/how-to-i-get-the-property-belonging-to-a-custom-attribute

Comment: Well it depends of your use case, sometimes its easier just to use CustomAttribute[name="something"]. But I think you should use reflection if you want, what you want. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property

Comment: Actually, that is the opposite of what I am looking for (the above link allows for finding properties where an attribute has been provided, and you get the name and value).  What I am looking for is once the CustomAttribute code is called, the CustomAttribute code knows that it was called from the name property and can detect the property's value.  If I could detect the class name and property name from within CustomAttribute, I could use Reflection to get the value, but I can't seem to do that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve, and why do you think that attributes is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  This is only available with .Net 4.5 and later though.

In the System.Runtime.CompilerServices library, there is a CallerMemberNameAttribute class available.  To get the name of the calling class, there is a CallerFilePathAttribute class that returns the full path of the calling class for later use with Reflection.  Both are used as follows:

```
public class CustomAttribute1: Attribute
{
    public CustomAttribute1([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null, [CallerFilePath] string filePath = null)
    {
        //Returns "Name"            
        Console.WriteLine(propertyName);

        //Returns full path of the calling class
        Console.WriteLine(filePath);
    }
}
```

I hope you find this as helpful in your work.